# How to change the avro schema

Tags: avro

I have create a avro file like below

```
CREATE TABLE msi ( 
Id STRING,
Phone_Number STRING,
q1 STRING,
q2 STRING)  ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' STORED AS avro;
```

Now I want to change the schema of that avro. i.e I want to include some columns into that table.
How can I do that.

Answer (score 0):

that's not avro?  Avro would look like:

```
{"namespace": "com.hp.ts.sa.streaming.messages",
    "type": "msi",
    "name": "msi",
    "fields": [
        {
            "name": "id",
            "type": "string"
        },
        {
            "name": "q1",
            "type": "string"
        },
        {
            "name": "q2",
            "type": "string"
        }
    ]
}
```